# Unable to execute javah on ubuntu12.04

Tags: java

I am using sun-jdk which is installed in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32 directory. Even though I can see javah file in its bin folder, I am unable to execute javah command. Every time I execute javah, I get following response from system:-

The program 'javah' can be found in the following packages:

- gcj-4.6-jdk
- openjdk-6-jdk
- gcj-4.5-jdk
- openjdk-7-jdk**
  Try:apt-get install

Please suggest me some measure to handle this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin` in your `PATH`?

Comment: ye i have added it in /etc/environment file with following values........

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32"
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME"

Comment: It's not `$JAVA_HOME` you need to add to `PATH`, it's `$JAVA_HOME/bin`. You don't need to add `$JRE_PATH/bin` (or `$JRE_PATH`), the JDK is a superset of the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever set up the Java's enviroment?
This is my JDK settings in /etc/profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=_YOUR_JDK_DIRECTORY
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have already done it in /etc/environment file.... Following are its contents:-

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32"
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME"

Comment: I have posted my settings, you can copy it and modify a bit. Just remember to paste them at the end of the file. Doing a re-longin can test wheather it is work or not.

Comment: You don't need both `$JAVA_HOME/bin` AND `$JRE_HOME/bin` in the `PATH`, the JDK is a superset of the JRE. You don't need `CLASSPATH` either.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple path problem, when you are executing javah command it is trying to execute the command from default java of ubuntu,

follow this steps,

- go to usr/bin folder
- search for java icon like this image

else

open terminal and write 'whereis java', it will give you correct path of your jdk folder.

[image]

- right click on it, and select `cut`, go to desktop and `paste` it.
- done.

Comment: I checked it out, its pointing towards /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java. How can i change it to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java???

Comment: ok, go to terminal & type 'whereis java' it will give you correct path of your jdk folder, just write that path in JAVA_HOME, will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

try type this in terminal with root

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac 1

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java 1

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javaws 1

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/jar 1

Comment: i made all the changes, but still same problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`. Preferably at the beginning if you already have a `/usr/bin/java`, otherwise the one installed with Ubuntu (a JRE probably) could shadow the one you want to use.

---

Check what's in your `PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Check which executables are seen:

```
$ which java
$ which javac
```

Comment: I did it but the problem still persists